# using inner join to joining 3 tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

### How to join 3 tables?

```
select * 
from tblcustomer as cust 
    inner join (tblamountdetails as det on det.[CustomerID]=cust.[CustomerID]) 
    inner join (select cash.AccountID, sum(Amount) as [Paid Amount] 
                from tblcashdetails as cash 
                group by cash.AccountID) as cash2 
        on cash2.AccountID=det.AccountID
```

---

table format:

```
1) cutomertable:
    customerid | customername | Address | phone
        1            arun       palani    1212112221
        2            aaa        sssss    123123123

2)Amountdetailtable:
    AccountID | customerid | Total amount | Daily Amount
        1            1            12000        120

3)cashtable : 
    AccountID |   customerid | amount(given day by day)
        1            1                120
        1            1                120
```

finally i want like tis....

```
    customerid | customername |AccountID| totalamount | daily amount | amount(given)
        1            arun          1        12000            120         240(this is sum of amount in table 3 where custid=1)
```

Comment: What's your actual question? You've shown a query. Does it produce errors? Incorrect results?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using, MySQL/Oracle/SQL Server etc?

Comment: i'm using MS access as database....i tried tis query "select * 
from tblcustomer as cust 
    inner join (tblamountdetails as det on det.[CustomerID]=cust.[CustomerID]) ...... i'm getting "syntax error in from clause"
    inner join (select cash.AccountID, sum(Amount) as [Paid Amount] 
                from tblcashdetails as cash 
                group by cash.AccountID) as cash2 
        on cash2.AccountID=det.AccountID"......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
SELECT DISTINCTROW tblamountdetails.CustomerID,tblcustomer.[Customer Name],tblamountdetails.AccountID,tblamountdetails.[Total Amount], tblamountdetails.[Daily Amount],Sum(tblcashdetails.Amount) AS [Amount Given],(tblamountdetails.[Total Amount]-[Amount Given]) AS [Balance] FROM (tblcustomer RIGHT JOIN tblamountdetails ON tblcustomer.[CustomerID] = tblamountdetails.[CustomerID]) LEFT JOIN tblcashdetails ON tblamountdetails.[AccountID] = tblcashdetails.[AccountID] GROUP BY tblamountdetails.AccountID, tblamountdetails.CustomerID, tblamountdetails.[Total Amount], tblamountdetails.[Daily Amount], tblcustomer.[Customer Name]"

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
    cust.customerid,
    cust.customername,
    amt.AccountID,
    amt.[Total amount],
    amt.[Daily Amount],
    t.amountgiven
from cutomertable cust
inner join Amountdetailtable amt on cust.customerid=amt.customerid
inner join (select SUM(amount) amountgiven,customerid from cashtable group by customerid)t 
on t.customerid=cust.customerid
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b9b1/1)**

***Fiddle took a lot of time***

Comment: :i'm getting following error.......Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'cust.customerid=amt.customerid inner join (select SUM(amount) amountgiven,customerid from cashtable group by customerid)t on t.customerid=cust.customeri'.

Comment: @arun what DBMS are you using?

Comment: @arun Try this code **`select 
    cust.customerid,
    cust.customername,
    amt.AccountID,
    amt.[Total amount],
    amt.[Daily Amount],
    t.amountgiven
from (cutomertable AS cust
inner join Amountdetailtable AS amt on cust.customerid=amt.customerid)
inner join (select SUM(amount) AS amountgiven,customerid from cashtable group by customerid) AS t 
on t.customerid=cust.customerid`**

Comment: @arun did it my query in above comment helped you??

Comment: @arun then please post your Query and tick as answer or else tick the best answer from the given set

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT *
FROM tblcustomer cust
INNER JOIN tblamountdetails det ON det.[CustomerID] = cust.[CustomerID]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
          cash.AccountID
        , [Paid Amount] = SUM(Amount) 
    FROM tblcashdetails cash
    GROUP BY cash.AccountID
) cash2 ON cash2.AccountID = det.AccountID
```

Comment: i tried tat but i'm getting error "Syntax error in FROM clause"